# C# DataTable not showing last column values

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, data-binding, datatable

```
DataTable dt;
```

I'm having problems with `DataTable`. I have a list of `double[]` but it refuses to show the last column values.

[image: DataTable old]

```
        for (int j = 0; j < header.Count; j++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header[j]);
        }
        dt.Columns.Add("Extra");
        if ((dataIn as List<double[]>) != null)
        {
            // dataIn = a list of 2 arrays of 3.
            localDataInDouble = dataIn as List<double[]>;
            //Add rows to table
            for (int j = 0; j < localDataInDouble.Count; j++)
            {
                workRow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < header.Count; i++)
                {
                    workRow[header[i]] = localDataInDouble[j][i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(workRow);
            }
            dt.Rows[0][2] = "hello";
            dt.Rows[0][3] = 2.55;
            dt.Rows[1][2] = 2.55;
            dt.Rows[1][3] = 2.55;
        }

        this.csvContent.ItemsSource = this.dt.DefaultView;
        foreach (DataRowView v in this.csvContent.Items)
        {
            var row = v.Row;
            foreach (object o in row.ItemArray)
            {
                Console.Write(o + ";");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

[image: Console]
[image: DataTable Extra]

As you can see the values of the `DataTable` are set correctly, but it does not display them in the `DataTable` itself.

I tried adding an "Extra" column in hopes that it would just be last column and then hide the extra column, but that is also not what is happening.

I also set some data in the `DataRow` manually, because it worked with the Extra row.

If I add another column to the `csv` file "Toff" shows its values but the column I added in the `csv` file / inputList has no values.

[image: extra csv column]

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also tried to add the Extra column in the header list and an extra value in the inputList. This doesn't work either.

EDIT 2:  XAML

```
<ScrollViewer Name="topLevel" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid Name="csvContent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10" CanUserAddRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Mode=TwoWay }" />
```

Comment: Did you try to enlarge a bit that column displayed by a ListView? The data is present in the table so the problem is just a visualization problem

Comment: @Steve Yes. But it still doesn't show it. Added a new image.

Comment: Trying to set a number instead of "Hello"?

Comment: @Steve also did that :(

Comment: I would look at the xaml of your gridview

Comment: <ScrollViewer Name="topLevel" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >

<Grid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
- - - - - - - - - - - 
<DataGrid Name="csvContent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10" CanUserAddRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Mode=TwoWay }" /> Seems normal enough right?

Comment: Yes, I can't tell you what is wrong here. Let's hope some WPF guru could help you better. By the way, add the WPF tag and remove the pretty useless datatable, dataview etc... This will be better to attract the right people on your question

Comment: Change From : header.Count to dt.Columns.Count.  It looks like you created a datatable with one column Cycle.  then you added two columns using header.Count.  So the array of headers has two columns and the datatable has three columns.  When you are adding the rows to the xaml you are adding only two columns instead of three.

Comment: no the `header` is an array of 3 as well. "Cycle", "Ton" and "Toff". `dt.Columns.Count` is 0 when adding columns.

Comment: Your codes are displaying correctly for me. There must be something wrong with your UI that we're not seeing.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I'll look at it in two weeks :(

Comment: It has to do with line endings. One file has LF and the other one as CR,LF.

Comment: even tho all values are read from both files. Have not solved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was caused by '/' character which I replaced with utf version of slash \u2215. I googled a bit after and found that there are others who have the same issue. I suppose that there might be more 'problematic' characters.